# OnlyOffice error converting file -7 (input error)

Tags: file-conversion, onlyoffice

When I submit a request according to the documentation, I get an error -7. It is not clear from the logs what the problem is. When I look at the logs, the problem is in the outputtype, but I seem to be entering it correctly. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Postman screen:[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDFAw.png)

Log screen:[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEGPz.png)

Documentation: https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/conversionapi

Request body:

```
{
    "async": false,
    "filetype": "docx",
    "outputtype": "pdf",
    "title": "test.docx",
    "url": "http://192.168.0.215:8089/example/download?fileName=test.docx"
}
```

I tried several different versions running in the docker container, but the error is still the same.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to use the URL of the document from the test example.
The test example is not intended to be used as a file storage.
It's best to upload the file to some other storage and send another direct URL for the Document Server. For example, you can run your own http server: `http-server - npm 3`

Additionally, make sure that you are passing JWT correctly as it can also be related to the issue. Please share the example of how you are passing the JWT authentication at this point. Finally, I advise to specify `key` parameter in the request body as well in this scenario to avoid issues.